# How do I load separate pages based on params for the dynamic route in nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am working on a nuxt project, and I have a folder structure like this.

- _category

  - _subCategory

    - _pageAlias

      - _post.vue
    - _pageAlias.vue
    - anotherPage.vue
    - samplePage.vue
  - _subCategory.vue

**_pageAlias.vue, anotherPage.vue,** **samplePage.vue** are at the same level and working fine. **The problem comes when I have to add another page which is similar to samplePage but have different URL.**  All the above pages have different page structure and functionalities. But now I want to merge the functionality and looking for a way to define a custom route in a way that based I can check the URL parameter make an api call to find out the type of page and load the respective component.
Eg. A middleware where I can do something like

```
if(router.name === 'category-subcategory-pagealias') {
    let type = axio.get('api'+router.param._pageAlias)
    if(type === 'sample'){
        next({name: 'category-subcategory-samplepage'})
    }
}
```

***In short: I want to load a page component like a dynamic component based on routes parameters so that I don't lose any of the page methods like asyncData.***

I have tried using extend routes in nuxt config, but that doesn't work for this case because it will be a dynamic change in the router config.
I cannot use dynamic components inside a page; then I lose all the page methods.